# Extract response header value in IIS logparser

Tags: iis, http-headers, logparser

I'm using IIS LogParser 2.2 & I want to get the value of a particular response header.  Is there a function I can use in the query to extract the value of one http response header out of the `responseHeader` field?

I'm currently doing this, which is really ugly:

```
substr(ltrim(extract_suffix(responseHeader, 0, 'headername: ')), 0, index_of(extract_suffix(responseHeader, 0, 'headername: '), ' ')) as headername
```